# Matlab matrix to cell

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, vectorization

I'm trying to avoid loops in Matlab. How can I do the following matrix to cell conversion vectorized?

```
m1 = ones(10, 2);
i = [1:10]';
m2 = [i i];
c = cell(10, 2);

for i=1:10
    c{i, 1} = m1(i, :);
    c{i, 2} = m2(i, :);
end
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @beaker mat2cell() is the function to use here...this should work:

`c = mat2cell([m1,m2],ones(10,1),[2,2])`